# Coded UI - How to get website title and make decision based on static part and ignore dynamic part from Title

Tags: c#, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I need help to better make a logic to identify website title and take a decision. When I run the following code it fails because there is dynamic part which changes for example [Request for Permission] - [Customer001]. I want to ignore [Customer001] part of website title and just get the [Request for Permission] part and execute block of code. How can I make a correct logic?

```html
                var getTitle = ParentWindow.Title;

                if (getTitle == "Request for Permission")
                {
                    HtmlInputButton btnGoogleGrantPermissions = new HtmlInputButton(ParentWindow);
                    btnGoogleGrantPermissions.SearchProperties[HtmlInputButton.PropertyNames.Id] = "submit_approve_access";
                    btnGoogleGrantPermissions.FilterProperties[HtmlInputButton.PropertyNames.DisplayText] = "Accept";
                    Mouse.Click(btnGoogleGrantPermissions);
```

Please note that I am not get enough in Coded UI or coding and need exact lines of Code which will work for me. I shall be very thankful to you..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that "Request for Permission" is always there, can you not use .Contains ?

> if (getTitle.Contains("Request for Permission"))

Just a thought.